# Unable to read data from Specflow feature file Table

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am new to Specflow. While reading data from feature file data table I am getting error:-
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Type'

**Below is my data table:-**

```
And Select Type
    | Type       |
    | SampleType |
```

**Steps to read Table:-**

```cs
[Given(@"Select Type")]
public void GivenSelectType(Table table)
{
    dynamic data = table.CreateInstance<dynamic>();
    createType.SelectType(data.Type);
}
```

Comment: Solved Issue myself. SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic was missing from my project. Also instead of using dynamic data = table.CreateInstance<dynamic>(); I had to use dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();